# What happens to an inserted NSManagedObject when it cannot be saved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Does anybody know what happens to an inserted NSManagedObject when save returns an error (i.e. missing required property for inserted object)? Does the inserted NSManagedObject still persist or does it go away?

I've read that even when validation fails an inserted object still gets saved but was curious if it applied to a failed save. ([Core Data saves object even when validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000679/core-data-saves-object-even-when-validation-fails)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a save fails it will remain in memory (as long as the context still exists) but will **NOT** be written to disk.

Given that 99.999% of save failures can be tested for, captured and corrected during development, there is no reason to write production code to protect against this event.  Test and resolve all save errors during development and you won't need to worry about this situation.

FYI; the 0.001% chance that is outside of your control is power failure/disk failure related. Not something you can protect against.

Comment: Well...sometime it makes sense acting differently, for example if you have a NSDate *lastUpdateDate (saved in NSUserDefault for example) that represents the last time you synched with the API, and you send with the API request to have a diff for changes after that date, you may want to set the "lastUpdateDate" only in case the save doesn't fail, so that your updates are always granted to be succesfully saved.

Comment: Which is a developer level event. You put code in there to handle that. I am not saying that it is all magic and works. I am saying everything that would cause `-save:` to fail can be tested for and reacted to before production.

Comment: If save fails I throw an exception and crash. @MarcusS.Zarra is right, saves should never fail.

Comment: Disk full seems like an example of an error that you could handle (prompt user to make space and then retry).

Comment: Disk full is not something that really applies on the modern iOS but can also easily be detected and avoided prior to the save.